# Output of the 555 pin 3 high when power on

Tags: 555

When I turn on power of 5V of 555 timer, the pin3 is always goes high in the very first power apply. Can we fix this issue? I need the pin3 not goes high when power on, until I make the pin2 goes low. Does anyone have this same issue? How to fix it?

Comment: The chip might see a trigger pulse during power-up. Have you used the reset pin to keep the chip reset until power is stabilized?

Comment: Thanks, Justme. Please let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution to this issue can be using some pull-up resistor on the trigger pin. By default, the trigger pin is high and makes the output goes low. A large value resistor can be used. If the pin is kept floating, it can take any value between 0-5v as input so may behave unexpectedly.
[image: Pull-up and Pull-down configuration]

Using a resistor ensures the input is tied to the ground or Vcc and not left floating around, which may be causing the issue.
I think this solves the problem.